# Internal Mic shows up as unplugged in PulseAudio whenever I connect headphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

As the title says, whenever I connect my headphones, my internal mic shows up as unplugged. The headphones's microphone is not working, so I really need the internal mic working. My laptop is a Thinkpad E15 Gen 3, and I'm running Ubuuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Just to confirm that your special function key assigned to muting your mic is, in fact, disabled. On my Thinkpad T15 Gen2, I often forget to unmute my mic with this function key.